# The system cannot find the path specified error Installing Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2008 on my computer but it gives me an error when extracting files during the installation ;

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I installed that same Visual Studio 2008 version a lot on the same kind of machines (same hardware and OS).

Does anyone get this kind of error before? How can find a solution ?

Comment: Suggest migrating this to superuser, as it isn't directly programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Process Monitor to see which file is being accessed.

When you know which file it is, you should be able to determine if the problem is related to your machine or if the installation media has an error.